# How can I replace all internal urls in a string of html with their relative external url?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

Given a string of html like the one below:

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/thing.css">

<body>
    <script src="/nothing.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <a href='#a_hash'>A link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to be able to get the following:

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/thing.css">

<body>
    <script src="//example.com/nothing.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/styles.css">
    <a href='//example.com#a_hash'>A link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

And I preferably need to do this without a library, and in vanilla JavaScript.
Currently I have this regex to find urls (I'm open to new ones!):

```
<.+?(?:href|src)=(?:"|')([^"']+)(?:"|').*?>
```

Comment: Convert the string to actual HTML, and then use the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
.replace(/\b((?:href|src)=)(?!\/\/example\.com)(["']?)([^"']+)\2/gi, 
   (_,x,y,z) => z.charAt(0) == '/' ? 
   `${x}${y}//example.com${z}${y}` : `${x}${y}//example.com/${z}${y}`)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/JIg2jo/1/).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      href                     'href'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      src                      'src'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    example                  'example'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    com                      'com'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ["']?                    any character of: '"', ''' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"']+                   any character except: '"', ''' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \2                       what was matched by capture \2
```

```js
const string = ' href="nowhere"  src="/nothing.js"';
const rx = /\b((?:href|src)=)(?!\/\/example\.com)(["']?)([^"']+)\2/gi;
console.log(string.replace(rx, (_,x,y,z) => z.charAt(0) == '/' ? 
   `${x}${y}//example.com${z}${y}` : `${x}${y}//example.com/${z}${y}`));
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this ignores stuff like: `<a href='nowhere'>` and instead returns `<a href='//example.comnowhere>` How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: @Explosion It does not ignore that, it matches `<a href='nowhere'>`. If you do not mean to do that, you have to check for a period, and then you need `\b((?:href|src)=)(?!\/\/example\.com)(["']?)([^"'.]+\.[^"']+)\2`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/JIg2jo/2).

Comment: Ohhh, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't mean that it _ignored_ it, I meant that it did not replace right. It replaces `<a href='nowhere'>A link</a>` with `<a href="//example.comnowhere>A link</a>` as opposed to `<a href="//example.com/nowhere` (Notice the "/"!) Thanks for your answer though! =)

Comment: @Explosion It appears impossible to do that with plain regex. Either a second regex will be needed, or the replacement  needs to be a function.

Comment: Thanks! :D I also made a version which uses the DOM interface to find and replace it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227916/discussion-between-explosion-and-ryszard-czech).

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case you might not need JavaScript at all.
I learned about the `<base>` tag today: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Add this to your header and you should be fine:

```html
<base href="https://www.example.com/">
```

Comment: I'm using fetch to fetch a url's html and I need the links, styles and scripts to work as intended. Thanks though!

Comment: This works even for JavaScript files, as long as URLs are *relative*. Try this in your browsers console: `document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", '<base href="https://example.com">');fetch("foo")`. The request will go to `https://example.com/foo`

Comment: As soon as you insert the fetched HTML into the DOM, the base tag applies (as long as links are relative)

Comment: @Explosion does this answer your question?